# Joining two tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a question. I have two tables employees and salary and I want to display the full name and salary grade of all employee who’s grade_ID is 2 or 3 sort by employee_ID.

Here are the tables:

```
Salary_ID      LOW_SALARY       High Salary
1                1              250000
2                250001         500000
3                500001         750000
4                750001         999999
```

---

```
EMPLOYEE_ID     FIRST_NAME     Last_NAME   Salary
1               James          Smith       800000
22               Roy           Red         375000
2                Ron           Johnson     550000
5                Rob           Green       225000
```

I know I have to join the tables, this is what I have so far:

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT employees2.FIRST_NAME,
       employees2.last_name,
       salary_grades.SALARY_GRADE_ID,
       employees2.SALARY
FROM employees2,
     salary_grades
ORDER BY employees2.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

what do i do next? I am stuck. Can anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Correctly tag your question with the database you are using.  MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle are different products.  Choose one or remove all the specific database tags.

Comment: You don't seem to have any linking data.  Does salary data have an employee ID?

Comment: Your question is not containing all the required information. Try to rephrase your question with the required detail. Like What is the relation b/w these two tables ? where is the `grade` column exists etc...?

Comment: We would need to see additional fields so we can perform a join.  For instance, your Salary_Grade_ID is not listed as a field.  Does the employee table have a foreign key to Salary_ID?

Comment: Why are you all missing the link? A salaray is in a salary grade when it is in the grade's range between low and high salary. Isn't this obvious?

Comment: Hi, sorry I have finished reformating my data into a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ,E.FIRST_NAME
    ,E.LAST_NAME
    ,E.SALARY
FROM employees E
INNER JOIN salary S ON S.LOW_SALARY <= E.SALARY
                      AND S.HIGH_SALARY >= E.SALARY
                      AND S.SALARY_ID IN (2,3)
ORDER BY E.EMPLOYEE_ID
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 because you where the first to show the criteria necessary plus for replacing the ancient join syntax with an explicit inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have to use a join condition that compares the employee salary with the low and high limits of the salary rank, i.e.

```
SELECT E.*, S.* FROM Employee AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.Salary AS S 
ON S.LOW_SALARY <= E.Salary AND S.High_Salary >= E.Salary
```

If you want, you can filter by `Salary_Id` between 2 and 3

NOTE: This syntax should work in the 3 types of servers.

Test data, for SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE Salary (Salary_Id INT, LOW_SALARY INT, High_Salary INT)
INSERT INTO Salary VALUES(1,1,250000)
INSERT INTO Salary VALUES(2,250001,500000)
INSERT INTO Salary VALUES(3,500001,750000)
INSERT INTO Salary VALUES(4,750001,999999)

CREATE TABLE Employee (Employee_Id INT, FIRST_NAME varchar(50), Last_NAME varchar(50), Salary INT)
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(1, 'James', 'Smith', 800000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the SQL Server (2008+) answer.

```
SELECT E.FIRST_NAME, E.last_name, S.SALARY_GRADE_ID, E.SALARY
FROM employees2 E
JOIN salary_grades S  ON (E.SALARY BETWEEN S.LOW_SALARY AND S.HIGH_SALARY) AND S.SALARY_ID IN (2, 3)
ORDER BY  E.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the alias even in the ORDER BY clause and you also can remove the parentheses in your jointure condition (useless)

Comment: I like my code with parentheses for separation.  That is merely developer preference.  Thanks for finding the alias issue in the order by.  I have fixed that.

Comment: I agree with you, the parentheses make the condition more readable, it was just to mention that it's not required on this situation

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employees2.FIRST_NAME, employees2.LAST_NAME, employees2.SALARY, salary_grades.SALARY_GRADE_ID
FROM  employees2, salary_grades
WHERE employees2.SALARY BETWEEN salary_grades.LOW_SALARY AND salary_grades.HIGH_SALARY 
ORDER BY salary_grades.SALARY_GRADE_ID
```

So I tried using this script, it works but do i use IN to display the range of 2 and 3 in sqldeveloper?