# Join two tables using a medicore relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

table1

[image]

table2

[image]

table3  (This is the relational table of table1 and table 2)

[image]

How can I join table1 and table2 using table3 ? I need the following output

What will be the sql?

[image]

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: 'mediocre'? gotta love google translate ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to attempt to solve the problem on his own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two tables SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889588/joining-two-tables-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
SELECT s.studentname
    , s.studentid
    , s.studentdesc
    , h.hallname
FROM students s
INNER JOIN hallprefs hp
    on s.studentid = hp.studentid
INNER JOIN halls h
    on hp.hallid = h.hallid
```